# In a signal there is a peak, I want to find the start of the peak and the end of the peak

Tags: signal-analysis, python, peak-detection

I want to the start time and end time for the peak shown below.
The start and end are shown by the marked circles in the fig
As there are number of such plots and want to know start and end time for each plot. So if its an automatic procdure thats good.
Can any one help me with this
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Zoom in on the plot and place cursors at the points that you consider start and end?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you need an automatic procedure? How do YOU want to define start and end points?

Comment: I have edited tht questions. Hope it clarifies my question

Comment: If your curves are always as smooth as shown in your example (apart from the peak), why don't you just compute some approximate derivative of the curve and apply a (experimentally chosen) threshold to the derivative? (first large derivative -> start of peak, second large derivative -> end of peak).

Comment: I am new to python, so if you could share the code. it would be helpfull.

Comment: I used the following code: def derivative(self,sig,t):
        dsig=np.diff(sig)/np.diff(t)
        ind = np.max(dsig)
        print ind              the result it gave ind=378.688073913, but the ans that I want is ind=438

Comment: in Matlab "findpeaks" does exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried the findpeaks code, it doesnot help. IT just prints all the values of an array.So i Just trimmed the signal to get start and end. That worked for me